# Cocoapods install, then "linker command failed with exit code 1 "

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, carthage

I was using carthage to import frameworks, then switch to cocoapods today.

[Here's the Podfile.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RGsw.jpg)
then I ran "pod install"
no major error other than saying "[!] Your Podfile has had smart quotes sanitised. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice." which I think is not relevant.

Then I opened my project, build, error is 
[like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVEmQ.jpg) I thought it had something to do with ALCameraViewController, but after I delete ALCameraViewController line from Podfile and install again, same error happened with the next plugin,CVCalendar.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: It is stupid of me. I forgot to open the workspace and build. I went to the project file.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Bond said, you can either remove the first and last line and then rerun pod install.

What I would propose is to put the use_frameworks to the top and then change the quotes around AnZhuang into the same quotes as there are around your Pods. If you look closely enough, you can see those are smart quotes and you don't want that. Or just copy this:

```
target 'AnZhuang' do
```

The reason why leaving the target in your Podfile: If later you need Pods for a testing target or any other target, you'll need to set the targets.